# Difference between shift adder and Serial Adder

Tags: vhdl, microprocessors, digital-logic

Is shift adder and serial adder are same? I tried Google but I cannot understand difference. I have to use it in VHDL.

Thanks

Comment: A shift adder is used to implement multiplication by shifting a multiplicand. A serial adder is also known as a bit-serial adder or binary serial adder.

Answer (score 1):

**Serial binary adder**:
The serial binary adder or bit-serial adder is a digital circuit that performs binary addition bit by bit. For example to add 1010 + 0100, we will start from LSB.

```
0 + 0 --> 0 
1 + 0 --> 1 
0 + 1 --> 1 
1 + 0 --> 1
```

And your final answer is 1110.

**Shift Adder**: Is used for multiplication. For example if we want to multiply 10 and 10, we will start from LSB.

```
10 * 0 --> 00
10 * 1 --> 10
```

First partial product is shifted to right before added to second partial product. For getting the result.

```
 000
+10
-------
 100
```